# Simplest bubble sort possible

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Suppose I want to sort an array of integer of size n. Suppose I have the swap method

Is this bubble sort implementation of mine correct?

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
  if (array[i]<array[j]) swap(array[i], array[j]);
```

(I just want to know if it's correct or not, I don't care about inefficiency)

Comment: try it out - see what happens!

Comment: Isn't this not a bubble sort? I think this is closer to an insertion sort. Not that it really matters.

Comment: @Xymostech this is a bubble sort, it uses two consecutive loops to complete it's task.

Comment: Bubble sort is not a good algorithm. Just saying.

Comment: This isn't a bubble sort: a bubble sort compares adjacent entries to see which is larger, and swaps if they are out of order.  You'll swap elements "the wrong way", and do it for non-adjacent elements.  A traditional bubble sort would have `i` go from [0, n-1) and `j` go from [0, n-1-i), and compare `array[j]` to `array[j+1]`, conditionally swap them.

Comment: so if this is not bubble sort then what kind of sort is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not correct for descending-order sort..

think about `array = [2, 1]`, it output `[1, 2]`

You can make it correct by change `j=0` to `j=i+1`

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 for (int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
  if (array[i]<array[j]) swap(array[i], array[j]);
```

**But it's correct for *ascending-order sort***.

Simple proof here:

Suppose after each step for output for loop we have `a[0] <= a[1] <= ... <= a[i-1] <= a[i]`, we call this **suppose_i**

**suppose_i** is right when `i = 0`

If **suppose_i** is correct for *0 <= i < M <= N*. When `i = M`, we have `a[0] <= a[1] <= ... <= a[M - 2] <= a[M - 1]`. After inner loop `j` from 0 to M, we got `a[0] <= a[1] <= ... <= a[M - 2] <= a[M - 1] <= a[M]`. When continue inner loop `j` from M+1 to N - 1, a[M] will become even larger. So **suppose_i** is also correct for `i = M`.

Comment: Hmm - playing around with this a bit, I almost think it might be a correct implementation of an _ascending-order_ sort. Hard to prove correctness though.

Comment: @bdonlan you are right. It's correct for *ascending-order sort*.

Comment: In this reasoning "After inner loop j from 0 to M" it is a jump to (correctly) assume that sorting has been extended from interval 0..M-1 to 0..M. I don't think it is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct. Proof can be constructed along the following lines.

Always when j-loop (the inner) completes (so j=n, i will be increased as next op), then a[i] is the max, and the part before a[i] is in ascending order (proofs below). So when the outer cycle is about to complete with i=n-1 then a[i] is max, and the items up to the index i are ordered (and since none of the preceding items is greater than max) so the whole array is ordered.

To prove that a[i] is always max after the j-loop is simple: i is not changing while the j-loop and if j encounters an item larger than a[i] then that is brought to a[i] and since j has scanned the whole array it's not possible that it includes an element larger than a[i].

To prove that the items up to i are ordered is full induction. We will use the above statement about a[i] being max.
For i=0 trivial (no preceding elements). a[0] is max and "it is ordered".
i=1 (just for fun): 1 item got to a[0] (don't care about its value, it cannot be greater than max), and a[1] is max. So a[0..1] sorted.

Now if the theses are satisfied after a j-loop ending at i=k then the following happens:
i <- k+1
Let's say the current item a[i]=q.
j scans a[] to k. Since k is the max it will be swapped to i. The items beyond i are not bothered yet. So essentially max moves up by one, so one item, particulaily q was added to the first part of the array. Let's see how:
The sorted part to max is scanned by j until it finds an item at index m that is larger than a[i]. (It will find a[i-1] in the worst case.) The items up to m are sorted. Now a[i] will be inserted here, an all items in the range [m..i-1] will be moved up by one. Since m is a right place to insert a[i] so a[0..i] will be ordered after the move. Now the only thing to prove is that the j-loop in [m..i] really performs a move:
At the beginning the sequence a[i],a[m..i-1] is ordered, thus every comparison in this interval will trigger a swap: a[i] is always the smallest in the a[j..i] part. The swap (i with j) will make the j-th to be at the right place (minimal item to the front) and j steps on to the remaining part of the interval.
So j reaches i=k+1 (no swap here) and a[k+1] is max so no more swaps in this j-loop, so at the end a[0..k+1] is sorted.

So finally if the theses hold for i=k then they hold for i=k+1 after a j-loop. We'we established that they hold for i=0 after 1 j-loop, and from i-loop shows that there will be altogether n j-loops so the theses hold for i=n-1 which is just what we've promised to prove in the firs paragraph.